# Default Data Validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report where i want to display information on a selected hierarchy.
I have a data validation where i select: Geography or Products.
- If Geography is selected - the second data validation displays the list of Products
- If Products is selected - the second data validation displays the list of Geography.

the data validations contain the correct lists (i used defined names for each hierarchy and the data validations use list with indirect of the list).

the problem is that when I select a different hierarchy - the reports doesn't display any data until a value is selected from the second data validation.
i want the second data validation to set as default value the first value in the list (or a value that exists in that list).

is there a solution or a vba code for this?
Until now I have this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, MonthlySellin.Range("B4")
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Range("$B$4").Value = "Geography" Then
        With MonthlySellin("B7").Validation
           .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
              xlBetween, Formula1:="=Legend!$D$3:$D$83"

         End With
    ElseIf Range("$B$4").Value = "Brand" Then
         With MonthlySellin("B7").Validation
        .Delete
           .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
              xlBetween, Formula1:="=Legend!$I$3:$I$50"

         End With

    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That would require a [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event.  To access the data validation list, you'll need to reference the `Range("Listname").Cells(1).Value`

Comment: no matter how many times an user changes the level of the hierarchy, i need the second data validation to change automatically to the first value in the specific list.